# ESRI Personal Geodatabases in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis

I am having an issue loading any ESRI personal geodatabase in QGIS 2.6. I have a number of files that worked in QGIS 2.4 and having done the upgrade I can't open them in 2.6.

I have tried this with installations based on the standalone installer and the OSGEO4W installer.

It affects geodatabases created in Arc 9.2, 9.3 and 10.0

Has anyone come across this issue? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Same problem with QGIS 2.6 (Ubuntu 14.10 64bit) - no option to add FileGeodatabase like in QGIS 2.4

Comment: Could you specify your operation system?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean Personal Geodatabase, which has an .mdb extension, or File Geodatabase, which is a directory with a .gdb extension?

Comment: This includes only the mdb extension personal geodatabases. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like an issue related to this GDAL bug: [Problem reading MDBs (64-bit)](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5594).

Answer (score 2):

When loading a personal ESRI geodatabase into QGIS mke sure you click on "Database" for source type instead of the standard "File" option. ESRI Personal Geodatabase should then be listed in the Database type as seen in the screenshot provided.

Hope this helps.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer to a similar question here, it seems that this issue is catching a few people out.

[Opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis-2-6/139716)