# Opening ESRI Personal GeoDatabase (*.mdb) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ogr, import, personal-geodatabase

How can I open an ESRI Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb; ArcGIS 10.2) in QGIS 2.6 or above?

Comment: Have you tried this and received an error or are you asking if there's an option available to open ESRI PGDB in QGIS 2.6? The option is available in _Layer_ > _Add Layer_ > _Add Vector Layer_ > _Database_ > select _ESRI Personal GeoDatabase_ as Type

Comment: Are you using 64 bit version of QGIS on Windows?

Comment: I've tried to do this but doesn't allow me to save the qgis.bat file with the changes. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: It can depend on the OS.  The QGIS on Mac's gdal doesn't seem to do manage it.

Answer (score 25):

If you have installed a 64-bit version of QGIS on Windows and you find that Personal GeoDatabases (*.mdb) no longer work for you, then this solution might apply; I'm on QGIS 2.8.1 rather than 2.6, but I assume that the issue and thus the solution is the same.

The underlying issue relates to this GDAL bug: [Problem reading MDBs (64-bit)](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5594)

**Step 1**

Download the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

If you don't have a 32-bit version of office installed you can just run the executable.  If however you do have a 32-bit office installation you will need to run the executable  from a command prompt using the `/passive` option

[image: Installing 64-bit Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable in passive mode]

**Step 2**

Locate the qgis.bat file (mine is in `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis.bat` for example).

Add the following two lines:

```
set OGR_SKIP=ODBC
set PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE=DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%%s
```

**Step 3**

Open QGIS and drag the mdb file onto your workspace

*Voila!*

Comment: This just worked for me on 64-bit QGIS 3.0.0 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 14):

Provided you have successfully installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 64 bit, you can:

### Method 1 (works with QGIS 3)

In QGIS Settings panel -> Options | System | Environment add the following two variables:

```
variable name: OGR_SKIP 
value: ODBC

variable name: PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE 
value: DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%s
```

and check the "Use custom variables" checkbox

*note that in this case there is only one percent sign in the value of `PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE` variable*

### Method 2 (works with both QGIS 2 and QGIS 3)

In the Environment Variables panel of the Windows Advanced System Settings, set the following two new variables as User Variables or System Variables:

```
variable name: OGR_SKIP 
value: ODBC

variable name: PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE 
value: DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%s
```

*note that also in this case there is only one percent sign in the value of `PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE` variable*

### Method 3 (works with QGIS 2)

add the following two lines:

```
set OGR_SKIP=ODBC
set PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE=DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%%s
```

in your qgis.bat / qgis-grass7.bat / qgis-ltr.bat / qgis-ltr-grass7.bat before the last line, that usually is something like

```
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qqis...
```

*note that there are two percent signs in the value of `PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE` variable*

Answer (score 2):

In Debian and derivatives (may also work in Windows) with the latest QGIS (e.g. 3.16.11) and GDAL (e.g. 3.3.2) Personal Geodatabases (.mdb) could be added in three ways. However, `ODBC and Geomedia` drivers must be skipped by GDAL/OGR via `Settings>Options>GDAL>Vector Drivers` dialog:

[image]

Thereafter any of these approaches should work:

1. drag and drop the file into the QGIS canvas
2. expand the database file via Browser (Layer>Datasource Manager>Browser)
3. as an ODBC database with a connection string:

create a `~/.odbc.ini` with:

```
[my_dataset]
Driver      = Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Database    = /path/to/my.mdb
```

create a `~/odbcinst.ini` if GDAL has not created it yet with:

```
[Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=50
```

in QGIS : Add Layer > Vector > Database > Type: Esri Personal Geodatabase > New

[image: PGeo connection]

## Reference

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgeo.html

Comment: Not working with QGIS 3.22.16 on Debian 12.  Is there something I need to install besides `apt install qgis`?

Comment: ... `apt install qgis odbc-mdbtools` seemed sufficient per https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgeo.html to allow drag and drop through the same pass-the-file-name-mechanism as its "Alternatively, you can pass a .mdb filename directly to OGR to avoid manual creation of the DSN."

Comment: @DaveX I wrote that part of gdal doc as a follow-up to this answer. 
see https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/4558

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed works fine also on windows 10. Only a further suggestion for adding the two line to the qgis.bat file.

The two line are setting. So it is important to add the lines before the start of the command.

Probably it is undestood but if you are not careful, there is a risk of being mistaken.

Comment: Since this is the most recent answer I want to comment that it works but I can only get to load the feature classes (vector layer) but I do not see how to load  the tables and relationships contained inside the mdb. Feature datasets are also ignored.