# Connect to an ESRI Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb)

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase

**My environment:**

Windows 7 Professional:
Service Pack 1
64-Bit

QGIS:
QGIS-Version: 2.8.2-Wien
32-Bit

Microsoft Office 2010 Professional:
32-bit

I want to connect an ESRI Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) with the "Add Vectorlayer" feature in QGIS
[image: QGIS vector layer]

The problem is with the Access Jet driver.

**My Questions:**

Has anybody successfully connected to an ESRI Personal Geodatabase in QGIS 2.8.2?

Comment: use Datei (personal geodatabase is a file .mdb though file geodatabase is database)

Comment: What error are you getting and how are you trying to connect using Jet?

Comment: Is it a geodatabase though? Just because it's a .mdb (Microsoft Jet (Access) database) doesn't necessarily mean it's a geodatabase. Perhaps your Jet error is 'can't find the table gdb_####'. That aside you need to set it up in ODBC first see http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase about setting up ODBC for JET

Comment: This question _Has anybody successfully connected to an ESRI Personal Geodatabase in QGIS 2.8.2?_ is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis-2-6

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your inputs.

My source is an ESRI Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb). I can open the source in MS Access. The table GDB_ColumInfo, GDB_GeoColumns, GDB_ITEMRELATIONSHIPS, etc. and many Geometry-Table are there.

I have already created a successful connection on File (Datei) and File Type ESRI-Personal GeoDatabase (*.mdb). It runs, but it is a "READ ONLY" Connection.

But now, I want a Connection on Database (Datenbank) with the hope this will be a "READ-WRITE" Connection.

I read a lot in the forum, I must first install the correct Access Jet Driver. 32bit or 64 bit under MS Windows System Settings
[image]

I will now following the way from Michael Miles Stimson with [northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase)

Comment: Please ask another question, rather than posting a follow up as an answer.