# How to find Coordinate System of datasets inside MDB and GDB

Tags: coordinate-system, file-geodatabase, software-recommendations, personal-geodatabase

I have been given some ESRI personal geodatabase files (MDB) and file geodatabase files (GDB). I don't know the coordinate system(s) for these files. Is there a way to do this without using ESRI software?

Answer (score 1):

For feature classes in a file geodatabase you can use GDAL [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html).  Be sure it has ESRI [file geodatabase support](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) which I think is GDAL version 1.9 or later. You can use the [open version](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html) of File Geodatabase support this as well, I use this. [MDB support](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html) in GDAL comes in via ODBC. QGIS will open the GDB and MDB files as well. Or you could just ask the person who gave you the files.

Comment: Yes, QGIS will open the GDB and knows what the SRID is so I can get it that way. However, when I open an MDB geodatabase, QGIS asks me what the SRID is. This indicates that this information is  not stored in the MDB. Too bad, I was hoping it was in one of those GDB_ tables in the MDB. The person who gave me the files does not know what the SRID is either.

Comment: you can usually work it out. You should be able to view it if you follow these instructions.http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis-2-6. remember it may not have one.