# Access database file to QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, database, ms-access

I'm trying to import an Access file (.mdb) to QuantumGIS.
This database comes from a geodatabase from ArcGIS.

Can someone explain me how to do it?

I tried to import from **Add Vector Layer** > **Database** > **ESRI Personal Geodatabase** ...

But from there, I am confused... 
What are the next steps?
Do I have to connect it to an existing shapefile?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) using QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis). And this helpful resource: [QGIS: Accessing a Personal Geodatabase](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase)

Comment: FYI, I think it's easier with a fileDB (gdb)...

Comment: You can just drag and drop them in. However, very importantly it has to be a 32bit install of QGIS. Access does not have a 64bit driver.