# Opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase

I wanted to open an ESRI personal database (.mdb format) into 64-bit QGIS 2.18.14 on a 64-bit Windows 7 laptop with 64-bit MS Office 2010 installed. On my all 32- bit desktop, all I have to do is drag and drop the file into the QGIS browser window to add it to my project. Not so on the 64-bit system, where I get a `"Layer is not valid"` error.

I followed the directions at [Opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis), installing the Access Database Engine and adding the lines from Step 2 into qgis.bat, but when I try to drag and drop the database into the project, I get the same `"Layer is not valid"` error.

I can add the database following the multi-step procedure outlined in http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase, but this is a lot of work compared to simply dragging and dropping the database.

Is there something else I need to do to be able to drag and drop ESRI Personal Databases into 64-bit QGIS?

Comment: You need a 64-cross-32-bit driver. Searching for one is a little like a [snipe hunt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe_hunt), but the driver is much more elusive. Esri doesn't support Personal Geodatabase with 64-bit Server or Desktop products because obtaining fully functional Jet drivers in 64-bit proved so difficult. If you're wedded to Access, you should probably stick to 32-bit applications.

Comment: @Vince I think your comment is worth a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265302/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis#comment421286_265302):

> You need a 64-cross-32-bit driver. Searching for one is a little like
>   a snipe hunt, but the driver is much more elusive. Esri doesn't
>   support Personal Geodatabase with 64-bit Server or Desktop products
>   because obtaining fully functional Jet drivers in 64-bit proved so
>   difficult. If you're wedded to Access, you should probably stick to
>   32-bit applications.

Comment: According to @LaughU 's answer no 2 ''Questions solved by a comment" in https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/reaching-80-000-answered-questions-before-questions-on-our-site-reaches-100-000?cb=1