# How to edit a layer from a personal geodatabase in QGIS

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase, odbc

I want to open and **edit** layers from a personal geodatabase in QGIS. I have read this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/opening-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-using-qgis) and I follow the ODBC way to open a personal geodatabase in QGIS with success.

However, I cant edit layers in QGIS.

[image]

The editing toolbar is grayed out.

Can I edit the layer from a personal geodatabase in QGIS? Is it possible ?

Comment: Curious as to why you have to do this, from a workflow and organization perspective...

Comment: Can you just export layers to a preferred format, then edit?

Comment: @JoshC yes I can but I want to work with layers from geodatabase

Comment: To edit your layer from your database, first set the constraint in your table (by primary key) and then you will succeed ...

Comment: @Cyril how to do that  ?

Comment: I correctly understand that you have already joined your database and see the list of tables in the tableview interface in QGIS?

Comment: If this statement is true, then you select the table, click with the mouse, select "pencil" on the toolbar, then select "editing nodes", then click on the desired point and edit it.